# Retrieving a value for Dropdown List and setting it as selected item

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc

What I need to achieve is to be able to allow users to edit a dropdownlist item that was previously set by them. So when the dropdownlist is loaded, I want the value that they had set before to be the one selected, and they can choose to retain that value or change it. My code looks like this,

```
if (list[1] == "Chart Type")
{%>
    <label> <%=list[1]%> </label>
    <%=Html.DropDownList("ChartType", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text="Horizontal", Value = "Horizontal"}, 
            new SelectListItem{Text="Vertical", Value = "Vertical"},
            new SelectListItem{Text="Pie", Value = "Pie"}
        }) %><br />             
<%}
```

list[2], in my array, contains the value of the dropdown list, in this case, either horizontal,vertical or pie. How would I go about having the selected value based on list[2]?
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

you can set this value when populating `List<SelectListItem>` like

```
 new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Horizontal", Value = "Horizontal", Selected = LastSelectedByUser == "Horizontal"}, 
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Vertical", Value = "Vertical",Selected = LastSelectedByUser == "Vertical"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Pie", Value = "Pie",Selected = LastSelectedByUser == "Pie"}
```

`Selected` is a boolean property of SelectListItem but only one item in the list should have this value set to true